# Добавление Activity парсера HTML во Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, парсер, android-fragment

Суть вопроса такая:
у меня есть написанный парсер HTML в отдельном проекте, теперь я хочу впихнуть activity этого парсера во fragment 2 (вторая вкладка tabbed activity), чтобы он соответственно отображался в этой вкладке. Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить их.

Вот код activity парсера:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ParseAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ParseAdapter(parseItems, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Content content = new Content();
        content.execute();
    }

    private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
               String url = "https://www.cinemaqatar.com";
               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

               Elements data = doc.select("span.thumbnail");

               int size = data.size();
               Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
               Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
               Log.d("size", ""+size);
               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                   String imgUrl = data.select("span.thumbnail")
                           .select("img")
                           .eq(i)
                           .attr("src");

                   String title = data.select("h4.gridminfotitle")
                           .select("span")
                           .eq(i)
                           .text();

                   String detailUrl = data.select("h4.gridminfotitle")
                           .select("a")
                           .eq(i)
                           .attr("href");

                   parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                   Log.d("items", "img: " +imgUrl + " . title: " + title);

               }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

И вот код activity Fragment 2:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag2, viewGroup, false);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Впихнуть активити во фрагмент?! Вообще то идея фрагмент-API в том, чтобы  делать обратное (фрагмент размещать в активности). Правильным решением будет переделать активити парсера на фрагмент и тогда его можно будет пихать куда угодно (в вашем случае вместо `Frag2`).

Comment: Вынеси класс Content в котором идет вся работа из activity, и переиспользуй во фрагменте.